# Firebase Firestore listeners skipped in Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have followed various documentation in reading Firestore data. But why don't these two listeners method execute? When I debug via Android Studio, both of them are passed through the execution.

Attempt 1:

```
DocumentReference docRef = this.db.collection("gallery").document("animal");
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                if(documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: " + documentSnapshot.getData());
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: no data");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: failed");
            }
        }
    });
```

Attempt 2:

```
DocumentReference docRef = this.db.collection("gallery").document("animal");
        docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if(documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                    Map<String, Object> mapData = documentSnapshot.getData();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "loadGalleryItemsFromFirestore: not exixt");
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "loadGalleryItemsFromFirestore: ", e);
            }
        });
```

Data is available on Firestore as follows:

[image]

Did I pass something?

Comment: Do you get any errors or any log messages like `loadGalleryItemsFromFirestore: not exixt` or `loadGalleryItemsFromFirestore: ", e`?

Comment: No, there was no error, only all the break points I installed in each condition were not reached. A strange thing happened when I used the same coding in different activity (profileActivity), which pulled data from firestore and everything went well. Listener can pull user data from firestore.

Comment: Finally I can receive the results on onSuccess. It seems like some time ago the service connection to Firestore was interrupted or something else. I am still with the same coding structure that has received results in the listener. Thank you for responding to my question. Admin please close this question coz it has been solved